# How to return JSON response back from JSP to an $.get() call?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

In PHP, we return the JSON to an AJAX call like this:

```
json_encode($data);
```

How do we do that in JSP?

**JSP**:

```
<%      
    gson.toJson(map, System.out);  // last line
%>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$.get("lookup_all_phone_numbers.jsp")
    .done(function(data){
        $("#results").append(data);
    });
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a JSP file but instead have your controller send the JSON directly to the client. What framework are you using (SPring, Struts, etc)?

Comment: I am not using any framework.

Comment: Just write the JSON out via the HttpServletResponse object. You'll need to use a library to convert the Map to JSON first (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13340138/249327).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Sorry, I am new to Java/JSP.

Comment: You do not need to use JSP to return JSON format. I see, lot of people  uses JSP for html representation. If you want JSON, then you can return directly from code instead of JSP rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
out.print(gson.toJson(map));
```