# Send Array of objects using HttpPost in Android

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I have an app that sends an object to an api via HttpPost. I have some sample such:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Destination", destination));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Description", description));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CreatorName ", myName));
```

In this object, I have an array of "User" objects, which has a DisplayName and Phone. How can I send this array through HttpPost? The following is not recognized by the server (where the quotes are escaped):

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Users", "[{"Destination":"St.Louis", "Phone":"1234"}]"));

Comment: *"where the quotes are escaped ?"* what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that in the actual code it looks like this:   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Users", "[{"\"Destination\"":"\"St.Louis\"", "\"Phone\"":"\"1234\""}]"));

Comment: try read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340138/how-to-generate-json-string-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to convert the Array as String (or JSON string). Then encode it with your server after passing as entity.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(wurl);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(nameValuePairs.toString());
se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

httppostreq.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[0]", gson.toJson(users.get(0))));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[1]", gson.toJson(users.get(1))));
```