# Need to remove last comma in java

Tags: java

This is my code

```
jsonUIResponse.append("[");
    String finalStr1 = null;
    String finalStr2 = null;
    Iterator itr_1 = skus.iterator();
    while (itr_1.hasNext()){
        jsonUIResponse.append("{");
        //System.out.println("SKU1 in loop :::::: " + itr_1.next());
        String str = itr_1.next().toString();
        String str1 = str.substring(1, (str.length()-1));
        String[] str2 = str1.split(", ");
        for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++){
            String[] str3 = str2[i].split("=");
            for(int j=0;j<str3.length;j++){
            }
            finalStr1 = str3[0] ;
            finalStr2 = str3[1] ;
            System.out.println("entry2 :: " + finalStr1);
            System.out.println("entry3 :: " + finalStr2);

            if (finalStr1.equals("value")) {                        
            jsonUIResponse.append("\"value\":\"" + finalStr2 + "\",");
            }else if (finalStr1.equals("sequence")) {
                jsonUIResponse.append("\"sequence\":\"" + finalStr2 + "\",");   
            }else if (finalStr1.equals("availableinventory")) {
                jsonUIResponse.append("\"availableinventory\":\"" + finalStr2 + "\","); 
            }else if (finalStr1.equals("skuid")) {
                jsonUIResponse.append("\"skuid\":\"" + finalStr2 + "\",");  
            }
            else if (finalStr1.equals("partnumber")) {
                jsonUIResponse.append("\"partnumber\":\"" + finalStr2 + "\","); 
            }
        }
        jsonUIResponse.append("\"defining\":\"size\"");
        jsonUIResponse.append("},");

    }
    System.out.println("entryresp3 :: " + jsonUIResponse);
                jsonUIResponse.append("]");
    jsonUIResponse.append("},");
```

It would give output as below:

```
[ {"value":"4","sequence":"1","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325365","partnumber":"602016000951676","defining":"size"}, {"value":"6","sequence":"2","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325371","partnumber":"602016000951677","defining":"size"}, {"value":"8","sequence":"3","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325377","partnumber":"602016000951678","defining":"size"}, {"value":"10","sequence":"4","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325346","partnumber":"602016000951679","defining":"size"}, {"value":"12","sequence":"5","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325349","partnumber":"602016000951680","defining":"size"}, {"value":"14","sequence":"6","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325353","partnumber":"602016000951681","defining":"size"}, {"value":"16","sequence":"7","availableinventory":"10","skuid":"24325359","partnumber":"602016000951682","defining":"size"***},***]}]},
```

Above highlighted(bold,Italics) comma has to be removed . Kindly help on this

Comment: Why not just use a proper JSON library?! (Or simply only print the comma if `itr_1.hasNext()`.)

Comment: What is the type of `jsonUIResponse` ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use that ?

Comment: @Smith : it is string builder

Comment: @Raga Use your favourite search engine to search for ‘*java json*’ and you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: I did not find correct solution. Kindly help on this scenario.

Comment: @Raga If I search for those words I get plenty of examples. You're going to have to be more specific about what problems you are having, and possibly post a new question.

Comment: It is adding a comma even at the final loop . Have to eliminate that comma and just add only } and not }, at the end.

Comment: @Raga So you said. But do yourself a favour and use a JSON library. Not only will it put commas in the right places, it will take care of escaping, etc. too.

Comment: Please elaborate why an example like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340138/how-to-generate-json-string-in-java-using-net-sf-json#13340315) does not work for you and you need to do this with the String Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Acrually it is better to use JSON library to construct the object. 
In this case you can do it like this:

```
if (itr_1.hasNext()) {
    jsonUIResponse.append("},");
} else {
    jsonUIResponse.append("}");
}
```

Comment: @Raga Note that while this solves the comma issue, your code may still produce invalid JSON. The ‘real’ solution is still to use a JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is adding a variable count. Add this declaration outside of the while loop

```
int count = 0;
```

Replace this statemet *jsonUIResponse.append("{");* with the folowing statements

```
if(count == 0){
 //for the first element, you only need to add {
 jsonUIResponse.append("{");
}
else{
 jsonUIResponse.append(",{");
}
```

then replace *jsonUIResponse.append("},");* with these

```
jsonUIResponse.append("}");
count = 1;
```