# Any library that can help me create a JSON file with dummy records

Tags: json

I am looking at any library (in java) that can help me generate a dummy JSON file to test my code for e.g The JSON file can contain random user profile data-name, address, zipcode

I searched StackOverflow and found this link,  found the following link : [How to generate JSON string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340138/how-to-generate-json-string-in-java)

I think the suggested library https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker, seems to be useful, however because of security constraints I cannot use this particular library. Are there any more recommendations?

Comment: So basically you want someone to do your job? Have you tried anything at all by yourself?

Comment: While, I was really looking for some pointer to library or utility that can help generate some dummy. Look at the below responses, how helpful they are.

Comment: TBH, the question is low quality.

Comment: Apologies folks, perhaps in a hurry I didn't articulate this well.However the response from amirrouche is very helpful!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for instance [Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker), like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from json import dumps
from faker import Faker


fake = Faker()

def user():
    return dict(
        name=fake.name(),
        address=fake.address(),
        bio=fake.text()
    )

print('[')
try:
    while True:
        print(dumps(user()))
        print(',')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # XXX: json array can not end with a comma
    print(dumps(user()))
    print(']')
```

You can use it like that:

```
python3 fake_user.py > users.json
```

Use `Ctrl+C` to stop it when the file is big enough

Comment: Thank you. I have rephrased my question to state that I need java library. Apologies for not being clear in the original post.